# Howto execute shell command and display content on a webpage while running?

Tags: php, shell, command-line-interface

I am trying to start a cd rip with `cdparanoia -E 1` and want to process the progress bar.

The sample code does output content in browser but just after everything is finished. If its called in cli content is displayed directly.

```
$cmd = 'cdparanoia -e 1';

@ob_end_clean();

$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
while (!feof($proc))
{
    echo fread($proc, 4096).'<br>';
    flush();
    @ob_flush();
}
```

My env is debian with nginx 1.6.2 and php5-fpm 5.6.17.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'd say you need to constantly reload the page for that.

Comment: I have worked with `exec()` and `system()` but both just give the output once and then finish. I guess on webside some ajax or HTML5 Server-Sent Events is needed + smth on php page that does not finish the program but constantly output.

Comment: You can't keep a server connection open for a longer time if you want to see anything in your browser.

Comment: *"some ajax or HTML5 Server-Sent Events"* ...websockets, maybe?